# Bookmarking and saving the bookmarks in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the bookmark in R shiny app and the save the bookmarks in a table. First stage I want to save them locally and retrieve them whenever I load this application. Then save them on a database. Here is the code for bookmarking and saving it on the table. The bookmarking as of now works where it does read from the saved RDS.

Also does bookmarking with `URL` work on `shinyapps.io` which can save the bookmarks to a database residing on AWS.

```r
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    sliderInput("n", "Number of observations", 1, nrow(faithful), 100),
    fluidRow(column(2, textInput(inputId = "description", label = "Bookmark description", placeholder = "Data Summary")), column(2, bookmarkButton(id="bookmarkBtn"))),
    DT::dataTableOutput("urlTable", width = "100%"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#bookmarkBtn { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "bookmarks.db", overwrite = FALSE)
   myBookmarks <- reactiveValues(urlDF = NULL)
  #
  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  #
  # if(dbExistsTable(con, "Bookmarks")){
  #   tmpUrlDF <- data.table(dbReadTable(con, "Bookmarks"))
  #   myBookmarks$urlDF <- tmpUrlDF[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct(Timestamp, origin="1970-01-01 00:00")]
  # } else {
  #   myBookmarks$urlDF <- NULL
  # }
  #
  # session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  #   tmpUrlDF <- isolate({myBookmarks$urlDF})
  #   if(!is.null(tmpUrlDF)){
  #     dbWriteTable(con, "Bookmarks", tmpUrlDF, overwrite = TRUE)
  #   }
  #   dbDisconnect(con)
  # })

  setBookmarkExclude(c("bookmarkBtn", "description", "urlTable_cell_clicked", "urlTable_rows_all", "urlTable_rows_current", "urlTable_rows_selected", "urlTable_search", "urlTable_state", "urlTable_row_last_clicked"))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(faithful$eruptions[seq_len(input$n)], breaks = 40)
  })

  onBookmarked(fun=function(url){
    if(!url %in% myBookmarks$urlDF){
      if(is.null(myBookmarks$urlDF)){
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token), by="URL")
      } else {
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(rbindlist(list(myBookmarks$urlDF, data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token))), by="URL")
      }
    }
  })

  output$urlTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    #read_rds("bookmarks.rds")
    myBookmarks$urlDF
    write_rds(myBookmarks$urlDF, "bookmark.rds")
  }, escape=FALSE)

}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2019-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach to my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53871448/9841389) using `saveRDS()` instead of sqlite:

Edit: Added username check.

```
library(shiny)
# library(RSQLite)
library(data.table)

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    sliderInput("n", "Number of observations", 1, nrow(faithful), 100),
    fluidRow(column(2, textInput(inputId = "description", label = "Bookmark description", placeholder = "Data Summary")), column(2, bookmarkButton(id="bookmarkBtn"))),
    DT::dataTableOutput("urlTable", width = "100%"),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#bookmarkBtn { width:100%; margin-top: 25px;}")
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "bookmarks.db", overwrite = FALSE)
  myBookmarks <- reactiveValues(urlDF = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })

  # if(dbExistsTable(con, "Bookmarks")){
  #   tmpUrlDF <- data.table(dbReadTable(con, "Bookmarks"))
  #   myBookmarks$urlDF <- tmpUrlDF[, Timestamp := as.POSIXct(Timestamp, origin="1970-01-01 00:00")]
  # } else {
  #   myBookmarks$urlDF <- NULL
  # }

  if(file.exists("bookmarks.rds")){
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- readRDS("bookmarks.rds")
  } else {
    myBookmarks$urlDF <- NULL
  }

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    tmpUrlDF <- isolate({myBookmarks$urlDF})
    if(!is.null(tmpUrlDF)){
      # dbWriteTable(con, "Bookmarks", tmpUrlDF, overwrite = TRUE)
      saveRDS(tmpUrlDF, "bookmarks.rds")
    }
    # dbDisconnect(con)
  })

  setBookmarkExclude(c("bookmarkBtn", "description", "urlTable_cell_clicked", "urlTable_rows_all", "urlTable_rows_current", "urlTable_rows_selected", "urlTable_search", "urlTable_state", "urlTable_row_last_clicked"))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(faithful$eruptions[seq_len(input$n)], breaks = 40)
  })

  onBookmarked(fun=function(url){
    if(!url %in% myBookmarks$urlDF$URL){
      if(is.null(myBookmarks$urlDF)){
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")), by="URL")
      } else {
        myBookmarks$urlDF <- unique(rbindlist(list(myBookmarks$urlDF, data.table(Description = input$description, URL = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url,"</a>"), Timestamp = Sys.time(), Session = session$token, User = Sys.getenv("USERNAME")))), by="URL")
      }
    }
  })

  output$urlTable = DT::renderDataTable({
  req(myBookmarks$urlDF)
    myBookmarks$urlDF[User %in% Sys.getenv("USERNAME")]
  }, escape=FALSE)

}

enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: So this works in shinyapp.io but all users can see bookmarks done by everyone. Can the user name be captured and filtered to show only those bookmarks which a particular user bookmarked?

Comment: How are you planning to identify a user? Are you using any special log-in mechanism? I'm not familar with shinyapps.io.

Comment: What I am trying to do was add this `User = Sys.getenv("LOGNAME"))` to ` myBookmarks$urlDF` and then filter in the outputtable like this `output$urlTable = DT::renderDataTable({
    subset(myBookmarks$urlDF, User == Sys.getenv("LOGNAME"))
  }, escape=FALSE)
  `

Comment: Okay, please see my edit. I used "USERNAME" (Windows). But you need to keep in mind that `Sys.getenv` gets the variables of the server side, not the client. So I'm not sure if this really is what you are after.

Comment: Got it. So when I do run this on shinyapps.io it returns the user name as Shiny. Even when I login with different users.

Comment: When you are using a database later on, you could try to use the database username for this check.

Comment: got it . But even then the username saved into the database will be from shinyapp user login details right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187592/discussion-between-ismirsehregal-and-snt).

Comment: When I use this bookmarks with navpage I am unable to retrieve the bookmarks. I did raise a new question  for it   : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465075/url-bookmarking-r-shiny