# Save R Shiny Bookmark to local .url

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, bookmarks

I have a nice shiny app and would like to bookmark the state of the app and open a save file dialog that allows the user to save a URL shortcut to his/hers machine for later use. Example code below. Currently the app only shows the ulr link but does not create a url shortcut or save it anywhere. Seems simple enough but I haven't found any post regarding this directly and I haven't quite got it figured out myself.

```
    ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    textInput("txt", "Enter text"),
    checkboxInput("caps", "Capitalize"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText({
    if (input$caps)
      toupper(input$txt)
    else
      input$txt
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

I've found the following post useful but its not quite getting the result I'm looking for. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465075/url-bookmarking-r-shiny)

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Your app is exactly doing what bookmarking in shiny promises: Generate a URL to save the state of the app (also have you seen https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html - its kind  of an intro to bookmarking in shiny)

Comment: @Thomas Yes the bookmark is working and provides a URL for the user save but once the user copies it they need to save it somewhere either creating a URL shortcut or saving it in a text/word file etc. I would like the app to open a save file dialog to save a URL shortcut for the user. Apologies for not stating this more clearly.

Comment: @Thomas yes I've seen that intro to bookmarking.

Answer (score 1):

I answer late but it could help the next visitors.
You can use the **shinyFiles** package.  The solution isn't aesthetic because you have to click first on the **bookmarkButton** before saving.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    
    textInput("txt", "Enter text"),
    checkboxInput("caps", "Capitalize"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    bookmarkButton(id="bookmarkBtn"),
    shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", filetype=list(txt=".txt"))

  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText({
    if (input$caps)
      toupper(input$txt)
    else
      input$txt
  })
  
  myBookmarks <- reactiveValues(urlDF = NULL)  
  
  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    session$doBookmark()
  })
  
  onBookmarked(fun=function(url){
      myBookmarks$urlDF <- url
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$bookmarkBtn, {
    print(myBookmarks$urlDF)
  })
  
  observe({
    roots <- getVolumes()
    shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=roots, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(roots, input$save)
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      write.table(myBookmarks$urlDF, as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: Do you need to even use bookmarking in this case? Couldn't you just have a regular action button to trigger the saving process? I guess you use it to generate the url... I am trying this with the server option so I am saving the state of the app to a .rds file. If you have any ideas for reading it back in that would be great