# Suppressing Bookmarking Pop-up Dialog on Input Change in a Modularized Shiny App while Keeping Autosave and Restore Features

Tags: r, shiny, autosave

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have developed a Shiny app that employs three modules. The main feature I'm implementing is the autosave and bookmarking feature of Shiny. Currently, the app saves a bookmark automatically every 5 minutes and users can also manually save a bookmark.

Here are the main steps:

1. When a bookmark is created, it is saved to a local .txt file along with a user-provided name.
2. The user can then select this bookmark from a dropdown menu to restore the app to this saved state.
3. The app saves a new bookmark every 5 minutes (handled in the server function with a reactiveTimer).

The issue I'm facing is that, currently, every time a user changes an input, a pop-up dialog box appears,showing the bookmarked URL. While this is a built-in feature of Shiny's bookmarking system, I would like to avoid having this pop-up appear so frequently.

Is there a way to modify the bookmarking feature such that the dialog box only appears when the app is restarted, rather than every time an input changes?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to modify the current app behavior. Thank you very much!

Here is a fully reproducible version of my app.

```r
# Required Libraries
library(shiny)

# Module Server Functions
module1 <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$num^2 })
}
module2 <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$num^2 })
}
module3 <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$value <- renderText({ input$num^2 })
}

# Module UI Functions
module1UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(numericInput(ns("num"), "Number", value = 0),
        textOutput(ns("value")))
}
module2UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(numericInput(ns("num"), "Number", value = 0),
        textOutput(ns("value")))
}
module3UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(numericInput(ns("num"), "Number", value = 0),
        textOutput(ns("value")))
}

# UI
ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(
        module1UI("mod1"),
        module2UI("mod2"),
        module3UI("mod3"),
        actionButton("saveBookmark", "Save Bookmark"),
        selectInput("restoreBookmark", "Restore Bookmark", choices = NULL),
        textOutput("txt")
    )
}

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    # Initialize Modules
    callModule(module1, "mod1")
    callModule(module2, "mod2")
    callModule(module3, "mod3")
  
    # Check if bookmarks.txt exists, if not, create it
    if (!file.exists("bookmarks.txt")) {
    write.table(data.frame(bookmarkName = character(), bookmarkURL = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), "bookmarks.txt", row.names = FALSE)
    }
  
    # Load bookmarks from file
    bookmarks <- read.table("bookmarks.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    updateSelectInput(session, "restoreBookmark", choices = bookmarks$bookmarkName)
  
    # Handle bookmark restoration
    observeEvent(input$restoreBookmark, {
    if (input$restoreBookmark != "") {
        session$doBookmark()
    }
    })
  
    # Handle bookmark creation
    onBookmark(function(state) {
    # Add to bookmarks database
    bookmarks <<- rbind(bookmarks, data.frame(bookmarkName = state$id, bookmarkURL = state$url))
    write.table(bookmarks, "bookmarks.txt", row.names = FALSE)
    
    # Update the selectInput
    updateSelectInput(session, "restoreBookmark", choices = bookmarks$bookmarkName)
    })
  
    # Handle restore event
    onRestore(function(state) {
    # Update the text output
    output$txt <- renderText({
        paste("Restored from bookmark:", state$id)
    })
    })
  
    # Set up auto-saving every 5 minutes (300 seconds)
    autoSave <- reactiveTimer(300000)
    observe({
    autoSave()
    session$doBookmark()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Comment: You might want to check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435930/9841389).