# What is a good design approach for a Shiny app with many filters: reset and preset widgets?

Tags: r, shiny

In a real world application of an R Shiny app I have a dataset with mostly categorical columns (dozens of columns). One of the reasons that this app exists is that it allows the user to quickly filter and search through the dataset by offering multiple widget to filter the categorical columns. The business background is "cases", of which there are thousands, and the user needs to find relevant and historical cases quickly.

In the design of the app, I have opted to have about a dozen widgets (mostly from `shinyWidgets`) to implement data filters. Specific cases of ongoing interest may have filter settings that are not easy to remember.
To make life easy for the user and prevent them having to memorise multiple filter settings, I have introduced a set of "preset" filter values. In my app, the presets are stored in an easy-to-edit yaml file (turning preset changes into a configuration task). A widget is available in the app that allows for the selection of these presets.
The filtered results are shown in a `reactable` table.

I have built the app to have the following behaviour:

- The preset selection widget is ignored until a value is selected.
- Once a preset value has been selected, the existing widgets will be updated to show the value of the presets.
- If a preset value has been selected, and one of the other filters changes value, the preset filter is reset.

IMHO this behaviour is easy to understand for the user. I am open to suggestions to do this differently.

However, the Shiny app feels complicated as there is 'to-ing and fro-ing" of reactive events. In the real app, the code becomes lenghty and somewhat tedious as I need to track around a dozen input values, update a dozen widgets etc.

I was wondering if here is a better (simpler) way to design this app.

Below is the code for a small toy app which has the same design as my real-world application.

Notes & comments:

- The toy app uses `palmerpenguins` as the dataset.
- The "presets" are expressed in a list in this example instead of in a yaml file (just to keep the toy app simple).
- I use a reactiveVal object to break unwanted reactivity that would otherwise reset the preset widget.
- There are three observers:

  - One to that updates the 'standard' filters once a preset value is selected.
  - One that resets the 'standard' filters if "no preset" is selected.
  - One that resets the preset widget one any of the other widgets changes.
- The helper function `conditional` simplifies the code.

Recommendations are appreciated!

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reactable)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(reactlog)

reactlog_enable()

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
      uiOutput("set_species"),
      uiOutput("set_island"),
      uiOutput("set_year"),
      uiOutput("set_preset")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      reactableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(dplyr)

preset <- list(
  preset_A = list(
    species = "Adelie",
    island = "Biscoe",
    year = 2007
  ),
  preset_B = list(
    species = "Chinstrap",
    island = "Dream",
    year = 2009
  ),
  preset_C = list(
    species = "Adelie",
    island = "Biscoe",
    year = 2008
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  conditional <- function(condition, success) {
    if (condition) success else TRUE
  }
  
  output$set_species <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = "get_species",
                label = "Species",
                choices = c("Adelie", "Chinstrap", "Gentoo"),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = NULL)
  })
  
  output$set_island <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = "get_island",
                label = "Island",
                choices = c("Biscoe", "Dream", "Torgersen"),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = NULL)
  })
  
  output$set_year <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = "get_year",
                label = "Year",
                choices = c(2007, 2008, 2009),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = NULL)
  })
  
  output$set_preset <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "get_preset",
      label = "preset",
      choices = c("No preset", "preset_A", "preset_B", "preset_C"),
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  })
  
  data <- reactive(
    penguins %>%
      filter(conditional(!is.null(input$get_species), species %in% input$get_species)) %>%
      filter(conditional(!is.null(input$get_island), island %in% input$get_island)) %>%
      filter(conditional(!is.null(input$get_year), year %in% input$get_year)) %>%
      mutate(
        island = as.character(island),
        species = as.character(species)
      )
  )
  
  update <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  # observer for the case when input$get_preset gets a value and does not equal "No preset"
  observeEvent(input$get_preset, 
               ignoreInit = TRUE, {

    if (is.null(input$get_preset)) return()
    if (input$get_preset == "No preset") return()
                 
    my_preset <- preset[[input$get_preset]]
    
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session, 
      inputId = "get_island",
      choices = c("Biscoe", "Dream", "Torgersen"),
      selected = my_preset$island
    )
    
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session, 
      inputId = "get_species",
      choices = c("Adelie", "Chinstrap", "Gentoo"),
      selected = my_preset$species
    )
    
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session, 
      inputId = "get_year",
      choices = c(2007, 2008, 2009),
      selected = my_preset$year
    )
    
    update(FALSE)
    
  })
  
  
  # observer for the case when input$get_preset gets a value which equals "No preset"
  observeEvent(ignoreNULL = FALSE, 
               ignoreInit = TRUE,
               eventExpr = input$get_preset, 
               handlerExpr = {
                 
                 if (is.null(input$get_preset)) return()
                 if (input$get_preset != "No preset") return()
                 
                 updatePickerInput(
                   session = session, 
                   inputId = "get_island",
                   choices = c("Biscoe", "Dream", "Torgersen"),
                   selected = ""
                 )
                 
                 updatePickerInput(
                   session = session, 
                   inputId = "get_species",
                   choices = c("Adelie", "Chinstrap", "Gentoo"),
                   selected = ""
                 )
                 
                 updatePickerInput(
                   session = session, 
                   inputId = "get_year",
                   choices = c(2007, 2008, 2009),
                   selected = ""
                 )   
                 
                 update(FALSE)
  })
  
  # observer for the case when any of the other widgets change value.
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE,
               eventExpr = list(
                 input$get_species,
                 input$get_island,
                 input$get_year
               ),
               handlerExpr = {
                 if (update() == TRUE) {
                   updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "get_preset", selected = "")
                 } else {
                   update(TRUE) # release the update of the preset filter, update is a reactiveVal object
                 }
               })
  
  
  output$table <- reactable::renderReactable({
    reactable(data = data())
  })
  
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use shiny's built-in bookmarking feature to manage the presets, as it saves you from writing code for each input update. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426953/bookmarking-and-saving-the-bookmarks-in-r-shiny/54435930#54435930) related post or some of my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A9841389+bookmark).

Comment: Also, consider using a [module](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) to define your filtering UI.  One instance of the module for each criterion.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution addresses the requested behavior and also dynamically creates and manages the sets of picker filters based on the column inputs, given that the intended use case expects a dozen or so filters.  This should enable adding (or removing) desired filters straight forward, based on the pre-defined PICKER_NAMES that map pickerInput labels to column names in the penguins dataset.

global.R

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reactable)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(reactlog)

reactlog_enable()


PICKER_NAMES <- c(`Species`="species",
                  `Island`="island",
                  `Bill Length`="bill_length_mm",
                  `Bill Depth`="bill_depth_mm",
                  `Sex`="sex",
                  `Year`="year")

PRESETS <- list(
  preset_A = list(
    species = "Adelie",
    island = "Biscoe",
    year = 2007
  ),
  preset_B = list(
    species = "Chinstrap",
    island = "Dream",
    year = 2009
  ),
  preset_C = list(
    species = "Adelie",
    island = "Biscoe",
    year = 2008
  )
)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 uiOutput("filters"),
                 pickerInput(
                   inputId = "get_preset",
                   label = "preset",
                   choices = c(),
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   selected=""
                 )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      reactableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Load the penguins dataset and set all its columns to character for filters to compare like classes
  PENGUINS <- reactive({

    df <- penguins
    nonchar <- names(df)[sapply(df,class)!="character"]
    for (col in nonchar) df[[col]] <- as.character(df[[col]])
    return (df)
  })
 
  #Reactive on our pre-defiend set of columns
  DATA <- eventReactive(sapply(PICKER_NAMES,function(x) input[[paste0("filter_",x)]]), {

    #For each filter and each data column, is there a match
    filters <- sapply(PICKER_NAMES,function(x) {
      filter_val <- input[[paste0("filter_",x)]]
      
      if (isTruthy(filter_val)) {
        PENGUINS()[[x]] %in% filter_val
      } else { TRUE }
    })

    #reduce for filters across different columns: the overall behavior that multiple selections within a picker will be logical OR for each value; and across different picker columns a logical AND filter
    filter <- Reduce(f=`&`,
                     x=filters)

    PENGUINS()[filter,]
  })


  #Run once: populate the presets options
  observeEvent(PENGUINS(), {

    updatePickerInput(session=session,
                      inputId="get_preset",
                      choices=c("",sort(names(PRESETS))))

  },ignoreInit = FALSE,once=T)

  #If a preset is selected: update those filters that are defined by the present and reset to blank those filters not within preset
  observeEvent(input$get_preset,
               ignoreInit = TRUE, {

                 if (!isTruthy(input$get_preset)) return(NULL)

                 selected_preset <- PRESETS[[input$get_preset]]

                 set_filters <- PICKER_NAMES[PICKER_NAMES %in% names(selected_preset)]
                 reset_filters <- PICKER_NAMES[!PICKER_NAMES %in% set_filters]

                 for (filter in reset_filters) {
                   updatePickerInput(
                     session = session,
                     inputId = paste0("filter_",filter),
                     selected = "")
                 }

                 for (filter in set_filters) {
                   updatePickerInput(
                     session = session,
                     inputId = paste0("filter_",filter),
                     selected = selected_preset[[filter]])

                 }
  })

  #If a preset has been selected; and the user later updates an individual filter, then reset the preset to be unselected
  reset_preset <- eventReactive(sapply(PICKER_NAMES,function(x) input[[paste0("filter_",x)]]), { 

    selected_preset <- input$get_preset
    if (!isTruthy(selected_preset)) return (FALSE)

    #What values to I expect to be selected, given the current preset selection?
    preset_values <- unique(unlist(PRESETS[[selected_preset]]))
    
    #What values are actually selected? (ie, has the user changed them from the preset)
    current_filters <- unique(unlist(sapply(PICKER_NAMES,function(x) input[[paste0("filter_",x)]])))
    
   return (!setequal(preset_values,current_filters))
  }) %>% debounce(200) #As we are updating/resetting many filters when selecting the reset, wait a second for all updates to complete
  
  #If reset_preset() is TRUE, it means user changed from a pre-defiend preset, so reset the preset picker
  observeEvent(reset_preset(), {

    if (isTruthy(reset_preset())) {
      updatePickerInput(session=session,
                        inputId="get_preset",
                        selected = "")
    }
  },ignoreInit=TRUE)
  
  
  #Render our pickers based on the pre-defiend list
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    
    peng <- PENGUINS()
    picker_ui <- tagList()

    for(pick in PICKER_NAMES) {
      picker_ui[[length(picker_ui)+1]] <- pickerInput(inputId = paste0("filter_",pick),
                                                      label = names(PICKER_NAMES[which(PICKER_NAMES==pick)]),
                                                      choices = sort(na.omit(unique(peng[[pick]]))),
                                                      multiple = TRUE,
                                                      selected = "")
      
    }
    return(picker_ui)
    
  })
  
  #Render the table based on the filtered DATA()
  output$table <- reactable::renderReactable({
    reactable(data =DATA())
  })
  
}
```

Run:

```
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: Thanks Soren, it will take me a couple of days to understand what is going on in your application. If I run it, it does correctly display the requested behavior.

Comment: HI Paul, thanks for the feedback.  I'll be happy to detail the answer; it's only "minimally" commented on the approach.  It would help to have your input where further clarification can help--ie, on the overall approach, individual lines of code, use of certain functions (vs not others).